# How to open default Set Wallpaper View from Flutter app for android device?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-apps-script, quora

In my flutter app i want to open android default set wallpaper view from app.
Like when user want any set wallpaper, user click on button and default android wallpaper set view open by default and when they set wallpaper, then after user will redirect to app.
I expect the open default set wallpaper view from flutter app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
// set wallpaper button
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  // save image to photos directory
                  _save();

                },
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xff1C1B1B).withOpacity(0.8),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                      ),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white54, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [
                                Color(0x36FFFFFF),
                                Color(0x0FFFFFFF)
                              ]
                          )
                      ),
                      child: Column(children: <Widget> [
                        Text("Set As Wallpaper", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white70),),
                        Text("Image Will be Save at Galery", style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10,
                          color: Colors.white70,
                        ),)
                      ],),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16,),
            // cancel vutton handler
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
                child: Text("Cancel", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
              SizedBox(height: 50,)
          ],),
        )

      ],),
    );
  }

}
```

More details here: https://ferilukmansyah.medium.com/how-to-build-wallpaper-app-using-flutter-90a2b23d1d97

Comment: Bro, I don't want to make UI, please

I want to open system set wallpaper view from flutter app